# To check the account_status and log the account

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

In the below code i have used codeigniter in my database i have a column name account_status it will be inactive by default .Now i want to check the account_status if it is active it should make me login else not.Pls help me to do .

Controller:

```
function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site1/members_area');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

Site1

```
function members_area()
    {
        $this->load->view('homepage_view');


    }
```

model:

```
function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you user anther column in where  with account_status in your model

Comment: I created account_status manually in mysql so when i create an account  it enter inactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these methods Just try this

Just use anther where condition in your model

```
function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $this->db->where('account_status','active');
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

}
```

Or check the status in your controler

```
function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            if($query->num_rows()>0)
             $status = $query->row()->account_status;
            else 
             $status = '';
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else //Account In active
            {  $this->index();  }
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code in model it is working fine but when i implement the code in controller it displays error : Call to a member function row() on a non-object

Comment: It displays the same error  Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\seatingreport4\application\controllers\login.php on line 22

Comment: Oh sorry in your model you have return $query not true just comment the if part in you model. and return $query;